# Page seems to load but not able to access data using selenium/python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriverwait

I'm making sure I wait for the page to load with `WebDriverWait` but it's still running the timeout exception and I can't figure out why. I also checked to make sure the XPath was present in the chrome developer inspector and confirmed that it is. Here is the snippet if anyone can help me.

Thanks!

```
url2 = 'https://www.rotorooter.com/adelantoca/'
driver.get(url2)
delay = 3
try:
    name = WebDriverWait(driver, delay).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '/html/body/app-root/div/app-not-found/div/app-local-page/app-local-map/div/div/div/div[2]/div[4]/div[1]/strong')))
    print("Page is ready!",name)
except TimeoutException:
    print("Loading took too much time!")
```

Returns:
`Loading took too much time!`

[image]

Comment: What about changing value of `delay=10/20`? After that also, not working then, that element is not in that website.

Comment: @Xitiz I changed it to `delay=10/20` and it still came back the same. I have added a screenshot in the main post of the developer console showing that it finds that xpath when I search it. Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: You changed 10/20 or 1st 10 and 2nd 20

Comment: I wrote it exactly as you wrote it. I wasn't sure exactly what it meant to be honest. Now I'm assuming you meant change it to 10 to 20 seconds instead of 3. I changed delay to 20 seconds and it still timed out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues here.

1. The main problem is that the element you are checking is far out of the initially visible screen view. So when the page is opened this element is not loaded until scroll down is performed. This is why your `WebDriverWait` fails on timeout.
2. You should never use automatically generated locators like `/html/body/app-root/div/app-not-found/div/app-local-page/app-local-map/div/div/div/div[2]/div[4]/div[1]/strong`. They are extremely unreliable and breakable.
3. It's recommended to use larger timeouts for `WebDriverWaits`. Making them too should may lead to false errors caused by low internet / slow web pages.  They do not cause extra runtime in the normal cases since Selenium code will continue immediately after detecting the checked condition.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. regarding your second point, is there a more secure way to write out an xpath? Thanks.

Comment: Sure. You have to learn how to create a correct locators. Take some tutorials and do some practice. Nothing can be better than learning and practicing things

Comment: Excellent! I thought the auto-generated method was the only way! Thanks for your help!

Comment: No! They are really, mega unreliable. It's very often when I see questions here with auto-generated locators, open the link and can't see those elements. And these are locators used on the page just loaded. Without actions performed there. While by performing actions on the page such locators are immediately broken in most cases...